# Another way to render all_each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in my view I use something like

```
= Services.all_each do |f|
  %p f.somesthing
```

I think this is not the best solution.
Need it at all my pages in sidebar.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What does Services.all return? An array of what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use partial if you want to make views common like these.

```
= Services.all_each do |f|
  = render "path", f: f
```

'path' here must be either full path or relative with name as '_path.html.haml'.

'_path.html.haml' must contain common code as

%p= f.something